# when i run this the compiler says :the assignment makes integer from a pointer without a cast

Tags: c, casting

```
int age[3];
printf("what is your age?\n");

scanf("%d\n",age);

int age[3]

age[3] =age+1;

int year[3];

year[3] = year+1;

printf("your age after %d years is %d",age,year);
```

Comment: You are using `age` as an array of `int`s and as a single `int` in various places.  And, as written, this code won't compile.

Comment: Your arrays are only length 3, so writing to `age[3]` and to `year[3]` is out of range of the array, which is *undefined behaviour*. Array indexing starts from `0`.

Comment: nothing about your array usage here is correct. You're also shadowing `int age[3]` by declaring it twice (and forgetting a `;`), I think,, not quite sure what will even happen with that. I suggest learning about arrays first,, you can start here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not getting what you are trying to do.
but a int array can't be scanned by `scanf("%d\n",age);`

you have do to:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
     scanf("%d",&age[i]);
```

Comment: The first line of code (third in PO's post) is legitimate for scanning an `int` into the first element of an `int` array. Whether that was the intent or not is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

and,

```
age[3] =age+1;
year[3] = year+1;
```

here, `age[3]` is a int, 1 is also int.. but 'age' is a pointer (address) which is pointing `age[0]`.

so, basically `age+1` pointing to `age[1]`'s address.
you can't store a address in a int type variable.

Comment: You do not need two answers: you can always edit the first answer to add more.

Comment: oops!! sorry!.. I am new here..  :)